# Apache not starting after upgrade to OpenSuse 12.1

Tags: apache-2.2, opensuse, upgrade

Few days back, I upgraded to openSuse 12.1 from openSuse 11.04 vai online upgrade.
Now if try to start apache server as -

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

it gives error as -

```
 redirecting to systemctl
 Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details
```

also i checked -

```
rtdp@linux-vai9:~> systemctl status apache2.service
apache2.service - apache
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; disabled)
      Active: failed since Tue, 06 Dec 2011 13:21:11 +0530; 3min 54s ago
     Process: 2688 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/start_apache2 -D SYSTEMD -k start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/apache2.service
```

Even if I try stating ngnix, it gives error as -

```
rtdp@linux-vai9:~> sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
redirecting to systemctl
```

and ngnix doesn't start.

What might be causing this. Tried googling but no help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start checking the logfile of the apache, especially the error log. Eventually raise the `LogLevel` directive. You might simply miss an active module, library or dependency for the server to start.

**Update**: Your problem is caused by the upgrade. Opensuse switched from `sysvinit` to `systemd` as you can read here: [link](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Most_annoying_bugs_12.1). You can read up on the issue in the bugreport: [link](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=725917).

The **workaround**: is to install the `sysvinit-init` package. As soon as its install gets acknowledged the removal of the `systemd-sysvinit` package will be suggested.

Comment: I have updated my question, even ngnix doesn't start. I checked apache error_logs, but it doesn't write anything there.

Comment: Updated my answer to assist in your issue. GL

Answer (score 0):

try using the server native script apache2ctl or htttpd2